# Response times within applications WebSphere Process Server goes down after a while working

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, websphere-process-server

I see a degradation in response times within myapplications. After a server restart, response times are acceptable. However, after some time, which depends on the workload on the system, the response times degrade and the server has to be restarted to return to good performance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you monitoring the Java heap usage with verbose garbage collection (GC) logs?

The behavior you describe can happen if the heap has enough free space after a restart, then gradually fills with long-lived objects as the workload runs. This may be caused by the heap simply being too small, or the application may have a memory leak, using heap and not releasing it for collection when the associated work is completed. When there is not enough free heap space, the application work slows down because the JVM spends excessive time running GC.

You can learn more about Java GC troubleshooting in our documentation
https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/vgclog/

You can also open a support case to get assistance from WebSphere/Java troubleshooting experts, if you have a support arrangement with IBM.